# Array declaration with assigning address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

As my teacher told me ,array declaration can't accept address as an assignment.

```
int a[]={1,2};
int b[2]=a;
```

This shows an error as invalid initializer.
But i was playing with such things and found 
 weird example as following.

```
int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int (*ptr)[3] = a;
```

This is also a declaration of an array whose address is kept with ptr pointer and this accept the address of 2 Dimensional array a,but this shows no error.
Why,can somebody explain me in simple words? thanks in advance.

Comment: "No error" does not always mean "works as expected". You may not have all of the compiler warnings turned on that will alert you to potential pitfalls.

Comment: When a compiler does not give an error, that means the syntax is correct. It does not give you any hint about the programming logic (in most cases). Tipp: Enable all warnings (for gcc, add `-Wall` to your Makefile or compilation command).

Comment: But it worked on online compilers as well.

Comment: Does "work" mean "does what I want" or "does something"?

Comment: it dispalyed what i want..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your second example, `ptr` is not an array but a **pointer to an array**.

This pointer is initialized with `a` which is an array that, in this context, *decays* to a pointer to its first element.  The type of `a` is `int [6][3]`, i.e. an array of size 6, where each element is an array of type `int [3]`.  So a pointer to an element of `a` has type `int (*)[3]`, which matches the type of `ptr`.

Comment: Okk @dbush ,this is declaration of a pointer but single pointer should accept address of one dimensional array rather than it's accepting address of two dimensional array.How?

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher is correct - an array expression may not be the target of an assignment.  However, what's happening in

```
int b[2] = a;
```

is that an initializer for an array in a declaration *must* be a brace-delimited sequence of values.  The expression `a` is not a brace-delimited sequence, hence the error.

What your teacher is talking about is situations like

```
int b[N];
...
b = some_expression;
```

This is not allowed - you cannot assign to an *array* using the `=` operator.

You can assign to individual array elements (as long as those elements are not arrays themselves):

```
b[i] = some_value;
b[j] = a[i];
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

The declaration

```
int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

creates a 2-element array of 3-element arrays of `int`.  Graphically:

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0][0]
   +---+
   | 2 | a[0][1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[0][2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1][0]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[1][1]
   +---+
   | 6 | a[1][2]
   +---+
```

Thus, when the *expression* `a` appears in the line

```
int (*ptr)[3] = a;
```

it is converted from type "2-element array of 3-element array of `int`" to "pointer to 3-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[3]`, and the value of the expression is the address of `a[0][0]`.  Since you declare `ptr` as a pointer to a 3-element array of `int`, the initialization works, and `ptr` points to the first element of the array (`a[0]`):

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0][0] <--- ptr
   +---+
   | 2 | a[0][1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[0][2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1][0]
   +---+
   | 5 | a[1][1]
   +---+
   | 6 | a[1][2]
   +---+
```

Since `ptr` points to a 3-element array of `int`, `ptr+1` will point to the *next* 3-element array of `int` (`a[1]`):

```
   +---+
a: | 1 | a[0][0] <--- ptr
   +---+
   | 2 | a[0][1]
   +---+
   | 3 | a[0][2]
   +---+
   | 4 | a[1][0] <--- ptr + 1
   +---+
   | 5 | a[1][1]
   +---+
   | 6 | a[1][2]
   +---+
```

Edit:

A handy chart for declarations involving arrays, functions, and pointers:

```
T *a[N];   // a is an array of pointers to T
T (*a)[N]; // a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f();    // f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)();  // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Things can get even more complicated:

```
T (*f[N])(); // f is an array of pointers to functions returning T
T (*a())[N]; // a is a function returning a pointer to an array of T
```